# override of android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" by applications

Tags: android

Is it possible to override the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` requests of other applications with an edit to the LatinIMEGoogle.apk manifest? I have edited the keyboard to be transparent and I would like the keyboard to always be in "pan and scan" versus resizing to the request of applications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you manipulating the stock keyboard?

Comment: In some webpages writing (particularly in landscape) on my nexus 7 in a text box the keyboard obscures the text making it frustrating to read back without moving the screen around. I knew the Optimus G had a trans keyboard which inspired me to edit the stock keyboard. I like the stock android keyboard, especially in 4.2.